# Can´t run JavaFX application outside ide

Tags: java, javafx, java-module

I want run JavaFX application with module but dont know how to do. I tried several times but i never got it. I use Eclipse, and export the proyect with the first selected option.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iASSN.png)

```
module MiProgramaInterfaz {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires java.xml;
requires javafx.base;


opens controlador to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml, javafx.base;
opens modelo.clases to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml, javafx.base;
opens principal to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml, javafx.base;
```

}

The last command i tried was this

```
java -p app.jar -m MiProgramaInterfaz/principal.Main
```

but i got this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
```

java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found, required by MiProgramaInterfaz

I tried steps from https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx but nothing

Comment: not sure what you mean by "run outside" - if you want to deploy a fx application, work through a tutorial on how to it (see the javafx tag wiki for references)

Answer (score 2):

You have two options To run a JavaFX application:

- Use a Java runtime embedding JavaFX, like the SDK provided by [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) or the JDK/JRE from [Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#download-openjdk). Then the command you tried should work. You can check if JavaFX is included in the runtime by running `java --list-modules`.
- Use a standard Java runtime. Then you must must add to the module path (`-p` option) the jars containing the modules you need, like `javafx-controls-17.0.2-linux.jar`.

When running a modular application, a jar must contain only 1 module. So building a fat jar file like you tried won't work. Select "copy required libraries to a sub-folder" and either use option 1 without using the sub-folder, or use option 2 and add the subfolder to your module path.